# ¿Como obtener value de una base de datos para mostrar en un input?

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

Me gustaría obtener los valores como tal para insertarlos por medio de un input al mismo tiempo que mostrar sus valores correspondientes pero no me muestra nada, que estoy haciendo mal?

```
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                          <select style="padding:0px;" class="form-control m " name="description" id="description" required>
                                <option></option> 
                                <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
                                  $description = mb_strtoupper(mysqli_real_escape_string($con, (strip_tags($row["name"], ENT_QUOTES))));
                                  $precio = intval($row["precio"]);
                                  $duracion = intval($row["duracion"]);
                                  ?>
                                <option value="<?php $description ?> "><?php echo $description ?></option>
                                <?php }
                          ?>
                          </select>
                          <input style="background-color:rgba(36,48,60,255);" value="$ <?php $precio ?> " class="form-control m" name="total" id="total" type="text" readonly>
                          <input style="background-color:rgba(36,48,60,255);" value="<?php $duracion ?> de duracion"class="form-control m" type="text" readonly>
                    </div>
```

Esto es los datos que me trae
[image: captura 1]

[image: captura 2]
Esta es mi base de datos

[image: captura 3]
Vardump($row)

[image: captura 4]
VarDump($description)

Comment: Pon un `var_dum($row);` dentro del `while` y dinos qué muestra.

Comment: Si muestra empty puede que tu consulta SQL no esté trayendo datos. ¿Haces alguna verificación al respecto? No deberías pasar a leer datos sin estar seguro de que hay datos.

Comment: oh ya entendi, adjuntare @A.Cedano

Comment: Pues el `var_dump` no viene vacío como decías. Podrías quitar el de `$row` y hacer ahora esta depuración: `var_dump($description);`

Comment: @A.Cedano acabo de adjuntar la que me dijiste

Comment: Realmente quisiera que al seleccionar cierto producto me traiga el precio y duracion de ese producto

Comment: Pero a ver, ¿cuando dices *no me muestra nada* a qué te refieres, a que no muestra nada en pantalla o a qué exactamente?

Comment: ¿Por qué no pones los `input` del precio y de la duración **también dentro del `while`** y así ya los tienes? El dato viene ya en `$row`, no entiendo por qué quieres hacer depender esos datos del `select option` ¿?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127263/discussion-between-aldhair-and-a-cedano).

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que no estas imprimiendo las variables. tienes que ponerles echo delante. En la imagen puedo ver que en tu select aparece el valor "PREMIUM 3" y ese es el unico al que le hiciste echo.

Dentro del atributo value en vez de oner `<?php $descripcion ?>` deberias poner `<?php echo $descripcion ?>`.

Comment: Nooop. El `value` es un elemento interno, y debería asumirlo. El problema es que las otras variables se están imprimiendo fuera del `while`.

Comment: De igual forma intente lo que me recomendaste y sigue sin jalar los valores

Comment: Si es verdad, los datos de la DB solo son validos dentro del while, no me fije en el scope. Gracias por la correcion @A.Cedano.

Answer (score 0):

Me he tomado la molestia de levantar tu caso, donde efectivamente tal y como esta planteado el codigo no muestra ningun dato.

Sin embargo lo unico que he hecho es agregar "echo" y ";", que por ejemplo no lo tienes aqui:

```
<option value="<?php $description ?> "><?php echo $description ?></option>
```

En resumen asi quedaria, lo probe y mostro la información sin problemas:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
      <select class="form-control" name="description" id="description" required>
            <option value="">Seleccione...</option> 
            <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
              $description = mb_strtoupper(mysqli_real_escape_string($con, (strip_tags($row["name"], ENT_QUOTES))));
              $precio = intval($row["precio"]);
              $duracion = intval($row["duracion"]);
              ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $description; ?>"><?php echo $description; ?></option>
            <?php }
      ?>
      </select>
      <input value="$ <?php echo $precio; ?> " class="form-control" name="total" id="total" type="text" readonly>
      <input value="<?php echo $duracion; ?> de duracion"class="form-control" type="text" readonly>
    </div>
```

Comment: Eso ya lo mostraba, lo que quiero es que muestre el precio y duracion

Comment: Tambien me muestra el precio y duracion, te lo confirmo.